# Como fazer um contador com zero a esquerda

Tags: php

preciso imprimir valores assim, com zeros a esquerda

> 00001
>   00002
>   00003

```
for($i = 00001; $i < 10000; $i++){
   validar($i);
   echo $i."\n\r";
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basta usar [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php):

```
for($i = 1; $i < 10000; $i++){
   echo str_pad( $i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) . "\n";
}
```

Resultado:

```
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
    ⋮
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7kiGv4)**.

**Parâmetros:** valor de entrada, tamanho desejado, caractere(s) de preenchimento, posição.

Veja a [documentação online](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-pad.php) para saber os detalhes da função.